# how to capture the wildcard and write elements to the wildcard list

Tags: java, generics

I've read a few topics about generic, but in this article's last paragraph [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html), this sentence "You can capture the wildcard and write elements that you've read from the list" really confuse me.

I have tested it in idea, here is the code:

```
class NaturalNumber {

    private int i;

    public NaturalNumber(int i) { this.i = i; }
    // ...
}

class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {

    public EvenNumber(int i) { super(i); }
    // ...
}

// test method, ignore class
    @Test
    public void redisTest() {
        List<EvenNumber> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        evenNumbers.add(new EvenNumber(1));
        List<? extends NaturalNumber> naturalNumbers = evenNumbers;

        // idea compiler error, Required type:
        //capture of ? extends NaturalNumber, Provided:
        //capture of ? extends NaturalNumber
        naturalNumbers.add(naturalNumbers.get(0)); 
    }
```

why "naturalNumbers.add(naturalNumbers.get(0))" is not working, and how can I implement the "You can capture the wildcard and write elements that you've read from the list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why "naturalNumbers.add(naturalNumbers.get(0))" is not working

Because you are trying to write into a list of **unknown** subtype of `NaturalNumber`. `List<? extends NaturalNumber>` represents a list of `NaturalNumber` or its sub-types such as `EvenNumber` and `OddNumber`. The compiler doesn't know the actual type.

> how can I implement the "You can capture the wildcard and write
> elements that you've read from the list"

You can implement it like this:

```
  private <T> void addNaturalNumber(List<T> naturalNumbers) {
    naturalNumbers.add(naturalNumbers.get(0));
  }
```

Here we say that the type variable `T` has captured the wildcard.